# Registered User and Unregistered user being brought to the same page. How can I differentiate the two?

Tags: android, firebase

```
 private void startUpTasks() {
    Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", false);

    //  If the activity has never started before...
    if (isFirstRun) {
        //  Launch app intro
        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, EnterInfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();

        initializeUserInfo();

    } else {
        getUserInfo();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Hi, so the check here will always go to the else statement. How can I seperate the two so that a Registered User is brought to the Main Activity screen after logging in and a new user is brought to a personal profile screen ?

It's for my fourth year project so any help would be amazing

Comment: Do you mean user who is registered using Firebase?

Comment: Yes, the users are registered through Firebaae

Comment: Check my answer. It should do the job